# NULL values in 3 last fields while saving Parquet - Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, parquet

When I try to save a `parquet` with Scala (Spark version => 1.6), in my output `parquet` file, I get some `NULL` values in the 4 last fields ; note that I didn't have this problem with the version 1.5 of Spark, and I wonder if there is any link between this problem and the `Spark` version.

I try to save the file with the following:

`dataFrame.write.parquet(output)`.

Do you have any idea?

Thanks for your help!